# How to debug running-time created JS Function

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use the Firefox Developer Edition, and writed some code just looks like below

```
const source = await (await fetch(someUrlToJsFile)).text();
const runningTimeFn = new Function (source);
runningTimeFn();
```

I use these codes to load js moudles myself, it works fine. The question is I have no way to debug these "fetched" js files, as they never shows in Sources.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYNsF.png)

At present, I use "debugger;" to debug these files. Is there any way better ?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Maybe you should use real [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) instead of those fetched functions..?

Comment: en...., I have the codes stored in the IndexedDB, and want the front-end and back-end use the same moudle loader. So the ECMA moudle may not suitable for me, I think.